# Is it possible to add interactivity to the HTML body of the email in an Outlook Addin?

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'd like to develop an Outlook Add-in which adds some HTML content to the body of the email.
If the user has this add-in installed, I'd like to add interactivity to the elements (for instance, replacing anchor tags with actual buttons that could trigger either a command, or open a task panel).

This would make the UX better by managing the entire user flow directly from the email content, without having to visit an external app.

Currently. I noticed that doing the following will return the string of the HTML content. But there's no way to actually `addEventListener` or replace elements in any way.

```js
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, callback)
```

If anyone could point me to the right direction, i'd appreciate it!

Comment: According to this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/it-is-2021-why-does-outlook-still-not-render-html/ed381bef-ca9a-4214-b457-3009ef094c5f. The Outlook desktop app uses the MS Word HTML Renderer (not even IE) - good luck getting anything to work as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this capability is not part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.